# Question about integral in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question About excersice 4.E of Bartle's *the elements of integration and measure theory*, the problem says: If $f\in M^+ (X,\mathbb{X})$ and
$$\int fd\mu < +\infty,$$

then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exist a set $E \in \mathbb{X}$ such that $\mu(E)< +\infty$ and
$$\int fd\mu \leq \int_E fd\mu +\varepsilon.$$

**My attempt**: Let $\varepsilon>0$ define $E_n = \{x\in X | f(x) \geq \varepsilon/n\}$ so that $\{E_n\}$ is a increasing secuence of sets, and let
$$f_n = f\chi_{E_n},$$

where ${\chi}_{E_n}$ is the characteristic function. $\{f_n\}$ is an increasing sequence and $f_n \rightarrow f$

But I don't know how to proceed. Could you suggest me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Monotone Convergence Theorem $\int f_n d\mu \to \int f d\mu$. Hence there exists $n$ such that $\int f_n d\mu > \int f d\mu-\epsilon$. Now take $E=E_n$ and note that $\int_E fd\mu$ is same as $\int fI_E d\mu$.

Note that $\int f d\mu \geq \int fI_{E_n} d\mu \geq \int \epsilon /n I_{E_n} d\mu =(\epsilon /n)\mu(E_n)$ so $\mu(E_n) <\infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: How can I assure that  $\mu(E)<+\infty$?

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality: $\lambda\mu(f>\lambda)\leq\lambda\mu(f\geq\lambda)\leq \int_{f\geq\lambda}f\,d\mu\leq\int f\,d\mu$ (where $\lambda>0$ of course)